# Swift: Realm accessed from incorrect thread

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I pass it from previous view controller. I want show data that I save in other view controller.

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "Beacons") {


        let nav = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
        let svc = nav.topViewController as! BeaconCharacteristicViewController
        svc.selectedList = sender as! Beacons


    }
```

and

```
      var selectedList : Beacons!
```

and this code that error for some reason.

i don't use a primary key or i have to use it.

```
    func loadproperties(){

      let beacons = selectedList

      let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {

        do{
            try uiRealm.write({ () -> Void in

                beacons.uuid = self.beaconUUID.text!
                print("uuid = \(beacons.uuid)")

                beacons.major = self.beaconMajor.text!
                print("uuid = \(beacons.uuid)")

                beacons.minor = self.beaonMinor.text!
                print("uuid = \(beacons.uuid)")

                uiRealm.add(beacons, update: true)

                }
            )
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }

       }
    }
```

Error

```
       Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Realm accessed from incorrect thread.'
```

Thank You :)))

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code `try uiRealm.write`, it seems that you call realm instance of another thread in the main thread (dispatch block). Try create another instance.

```
    do{
        // create new instance
        let uiRealm = try! Realm()

        try uiRealm.write({ () -> Void in

            beacons.uuid = self.beaconUUID.text!
            print("uuid = \(beacons.uuid)")

            beacons.major = self.beaconMajor.text!
            print("uuid = \(beacons.uuid)")

            beacons.minor = self.beaonMinor.text!
            print("uuid = \(beacons.uuid)")

            uiRealm.add(beacons, update: true)

            }
        )
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but It cause this error "realm::IncorrectThreadException: Realm accessed from incorrect thread."

Comment: have you try to remove the dispatch block?

Comment: It's ok but error Beacons' does not have a primary key and can not be updated' . By the way I will try to find a solution. Thank you for help:))

Comment: normally i add primary key, easier to get the object.

Comment: I will do primary key.